# Run Shell script using PHP

Tags: php, linux, bash, shell, curl

I am running into a strange problem. I have a button setup that when it is clicked it will run a shell script that I created using PHP. The shell script is two curl commands.

```
curl -H "Accept: application/xml" "http://blah/blah" > /tmp/listofchannels.xml
curl -H "Accept: application/xml" "http://blah/blah" > /tmp/listofnodes.xml
echo "Done!"
```

I've used `shell_exec()`, `exec()`, and `system()` to run this script with PHP and it runs successfully. BUT it does not redirect the output to the files `/tmp/listofchannels.xml` and `/tmp/listofnodes.xml`.

I have used `tail` on the httpd error logs and it shows the curls run. I even will see the `Done!` show up on my webpage when using `system()` but it will not create the files.

If I run the script myself from the command line it works completely. The files do get created but only if I run the script from the command line myself instead of using the PHP code.

Does anyone have any idea why?

I thought perhaps it was a permissions issue but I get no error stating that I don't have permission.

Any help would be great!

---

**Update**:

I found the problem and fixed it. It was SElinux. Maybe I should have mentioned I was doing this on CentOS7.
What I did was create a new folder and made the owner apache then allowed apache to write to it.

```
chown apache:apache /folder
sudo chcon -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t /folder
```

Comment: why not use php curl?

Comment: I mean I guess I could. I'm just curious why this isn't working... I mean it runs the script so why aren't the two files being created... I'm just wanting to understand what is happening now.

Comment: i would bet on a permission issue

Comment: You can add `true > /doesntexist/foo` to your script and check the error logs for `bash: /doesntexist/foo: No such file or directory` to ensure that you're looking in the right place. If you don't see it, you should find where the errors are going instead. If you do see it, maybe your web server is chrooted and therefore has a different view of your FS.

Answer (score 2):

I found the problem and fixed it. It was SElinux. Maybe I should have mentioned I was doing this on CentOS7. What I did was create a new folder and made the owner apache then allowed apache to write to it.

```
chown apache:apache /folder
sudo chcon -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t /folder
```